# AVERAGEIF get a column by a month name in its header

Tags: google-sheets

Basically, I have a table with a bunch of people names vertically and months listed horizontally. Then I have a drop-down list of all months. For the purposes of `=AVERAGEIF` I want to use that drop-down list to point to a corresponding column *without making 12 different named ranges* for every page with the same table I'll need to make in the future.

An example:
I want something like `=AVERAGEIF(name_range; Greta; March)` when `March` is selected in a drop-down, which will return an average between $2557 and $3367.

[image: example table]

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Would you explain how the value = `Greta` is determined if there is only one set dropdowns (Month)? Are you sure that you're not assuming a dropdown for "Names" as well?

Comment: Hello, @Tedinoz
I will be using requested formula on another sheet with a table of names made with `=unique(name_range)`.

Comment: Hi. OK - 2 things: 1) `=unique(name_range)` will only deliver a list on names, it won't enable you to select one. That's why I think you need the dropdown (or perhaps that is what you intended). FWIW, a dropdown will generate a list of unique values, so you wouldn't need to use `UNIQUE`.  2) For future reference, your explanation: _I will be using requested formula on another sheet with a table of names made with =unique(name_range)_ is pretty important and is the type of thing that should be included in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are likely to be many ways to answer this question. However you have specifically cited `AVERAGEIF`.

There is an existing dropdown to identify the Month.

- There needs to be an additional dropdown to identify the Name.
- With those pieces of data, try this formula
  `=averageif(A2:A6;H2;indirect(address(2;month($I$2&1)+1;4)&":"&address(6;month($I$2&1)+1;4)))`
- Or for those in a locale that uses a decimal point
  `=averageif(A2:A6,H2,indirect(address(2,month($I$2&1)+1,4)&":"&address(6,month($I$2&1)+1,4)))`

---

**Sample**

### [image: snapshot]

**Logic**

- `criteria range` = A2:A6 but you can sustitute your named range`
- `criterion` = value of the "Name" dropdown
- `[average range]` = supplied by `INDIRECT`

  - range based on `address` function

    - Row: Start:2, End:6
    - Column: `month($I$2&1)+1` this converts the string value of the Month dropdown into a number. Add 1 because the function is zero-based.

Comment: It works! Yeah, I was finally resigned to using named ranges. But then I had understood why this formula didn't work for the first time - my locale. In my locale, a semicolon `;` is a divider, so all formulae using a simple comma `,` will refuse to work.

Comment: My bad. I _did_ notice the locale aspect of your formula. Anyway, I've edited the answer to include added both versions.